# Converting .obj file data to NSImage

Tags: swift, base64, nsdata, nsimage, .obj

I'm trying to convert the data from a .obj file to a base64 string, so that I can display a thumbnail preview of the .obj file in an `NSImageView`.

Below is my code for getting the asset from a local url, and converting it to a base64 string. I then convert that to `Data`, which I then attempt to convert to an image.

```
    let fileUrl = Foundation.URL(string: input_string)


    let data: NSData? = NSData(contentsOfFile: input_string)

    if let fileData = data {

        let base64String = fileData.base64EncodedString()

        let decodedData = NSData(base64Encoded: base64String, options: NSData.Base64DecodingOptions(rawValue: 0) )

        let decodedimage = NSImage(data: decodedData! as Data)
}
```

I can see that I'm getting the data set, but `decodedImage` is always nil - I'm guessing this has something to do with .obj image format, which I may not know enough about. Any insight / help appreciated.

EDIT: Here's a screenshot showing what the .obj file looks like in the finder preview.

[image]

Comment: @MartinR In this case it's just a simple blob - I updated my question with a screenshot of a finder preview of it.

Comment: Not related to your question but if input_string is a file path you should use `URL(fileURLWithPath:)` initializer. The URL(string:) initializer requires that the string contains the url scheme, which in this case of a fileURL path would be "file://". Besides that you should update your Xcode/Swift to the latest version (Swift 2 is not even supported anymore by Xcode9). Btw looks like you have your own struct or class named URL you should change its name to something else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OBJ is not an image format.  Its an old [3D model format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wavefront_.obj_file).  If you want to convert it to an image you will need to open the file and add it to a [SCNScene](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnscene) as a geometry node and then render out the the [SCNView](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnview) to an image and save that image.

Comment: That does make sense, Josh. But, how then would the finder be able to render a preview as in the screenshot I posted?

Comment: I assume finder does exactly the same thing; except that it probably caches the resulting thumbnail so it doesn't have to rerender it every time.  Some 3d formats to include a thumbnail; obj isn't one of them.